# Are online auction sales subject to the sale of goods Act?

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, any-jurisdiction

Certain commercial regulations have specific exemptions for auction sales. Does the sale of goods act apply to auction sales? If not, what consumer protection regulations govern them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

Auctions are expressly addressed in [s57](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1979/54/section/57).